# Uploading Excel to Azure storage is corrupting the file and providing a Security warning as well

Tags: excel, azure, blob, storage

I am uploading an Excel memorystream to Azure Storage as a blob. Blob is saved successfully but corrupted while opening or downloading. Tested once with Excel

This provides Security warning everytime for the .csv files. But the file opens normally after that.

The same memorystream is working fine on local as I am able to convert the memorystream into Excel/CSV with no errors.

Any Help!!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written to upload the stream to blob storage. If possible, please share the URL of the corrupt blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after some Google.

I was uploading an Excel/CSV to azure storage and while opening the file especially .csv it produces a Security warning. But the same same memorystream was working find on local.

Got some interesting answer here:

"It is possible for .csv files to contain potentially malicious code, so we purposely don't include it in our list of safe-to-open files.

In a future update, we could provide a way to customize the list of files a user would consider safe to open."

The link is:: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/164

[image]